# Show df $> m-1$ for Welch two sample t-test

Tags: statistics

I am trying to verify that the degrees of freedom $k$ for a Welch two sample $t$-test with unequal variances has $k > m-1$. It is quite clear for the case when they have equal variances.

The formula for df is $k =\dfrac{\left(\frac{S_1^2}{m} + \frac{S_2^2}{n}\right)^2}{ \frac{(S_1^2/m)^2}{m-1}+\frac{(S_2^2/n)^2}{n-1}}$.

I have tried a few difference approaches to manipulate this but I haven't had much success. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: thanks Bruce, I will play around with this a bit.

Comment: As I recall, $\min(n-1, m-1) < k \le m + n - 2.$ Largest when $S_1^2=S_2^2;$ approaches lower end when the two sample variances become very different.

Comment: **Sorry.** TeX problem in Comment; fixed now: Alternate form for k from Ott/Longnecker (but in your notation) may make this easier: $k=\frac{(n−1)(m−1)}{(1−c)^2(n−1)+c^2(m−1)},$ where $c=\frac{S^2_1/n}{S^2_1/n+S^2_2/m}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment** continued: Special case where $n = 10, m = 20,$ and (depending on ratio of sample variances) $0 < c < 1.$ Plot in R statistical software.

```
c = seq(.001, .999, by=.001);  n = 10;  m=20
denom=(1-c)^2*(n-1)+c^2*(m-1)
k = (n-1)*(m-1)/denom
plot(c, k, type="l", lwd=2)
  abline(v=0:1, col="green2");  abline(h=c(9, 19, 28), col="red")
```

[image]